# Packages cannot be nested an error in flash cs6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

It's my first time coding in `flash`, I am creating a login form wherein when user login in flash the record will automatically stored in the database.

I am currently testing the button `submit`, but there was an error saying `"packages cannot be nested"`. Hope you could help me.

```
package actions {    

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;  

    public class main extends MovieClip {

        public function main ():void {             
            submit_button.buttonMode = true;
            submit_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, checkLogin);

            username.text = "";
            password.text = "";         
        }      

        public function checkLogin (e:MouseEvent):void {         
            trace("submission success");         
        }     
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Packages cannot be nested" means that you have an AS file that literally includes two blocks marked `package`. An example of nesting:

```
package a {
    ...
    package b {
        ....
    }
}
```

You need to revise your code so that no file contains nested `package` blocks. This isn't an error in programming, but rather a markup error (that potentially hides a lot of uneven braces or other types of copy&paste mixups).

UPDATE: A timeline code is declared as being inside a package, so if you are trying to add a `package ...{...}` block to a timeline, you will get this very error.

Comment: package actions {
 
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 
 public class main extends MovieClip {

  public function main():void {
   trace("success");
  }

 }
 
}
this is the code for my as file.It was not nested.

Comment: There shold be dependent files, check them. Probably your stage contains another AS-linked class instance, and *that* file has a nested packages issue. You need to review your codebase, not just one file.

Comment: Yes i have a dependent file, i've checked it already and there was only one as file. The code i pasted above is the code for the button submit (it's not actually a button but a movie clip, cause i'm just following a tutorial).Anyways thank you, your answer was very clear to me. @Vesper

Comment: If this code you are posting are partial file, then strip surrounding `package` block off it, and you should be good to go.

Comment: what do you mean?I'm gonna delete all codes inside the package braces?If that what you mean, I did it already and the same error shows again.

Comment: No, you delete the `package actions{` and the corresponding rightbrace at the end of file, not the code inside.

Comment: Thank you. I've deleted the package and there was an error saying that public functions should only be used inside of a package so i deleted that also and run it. It was a success.THANKS

Comment: try following the conventions as well, the main class should be named Main and the main.as should be named Main.as. Try giving a more meaningful name, it's a login form so why not LoginView or LoginScreen, etc ...